# Trois mois sont / se sont / ont passé(s)

Tags: verbes, verbes-pronominaux, auxiliaires

> Trois mois **sont** passés.
>
> Trois mois **se sont** passés.
>
> Trois mois **ont** passé.

D'après la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4106), la première et la troisième phrases sont correctes, mais la première est plus courante. J'ai vu plusieurs exemples contenant *mois se sont passés* sur Internet.

Quelle phrase est utilisée plus souvent, la première ou la deuxième ?

Comment: Il est vrai qu'on trouve une multitude d'accords avec s (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mois%20ont%20pass%C3%A9s%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) pour « mois ont passé », mais c'est faux.

Comment: se passer verbe pronominalConjugaison
 1. S'écouler, en parlant du temps : Deux mois s'étaient passés depuis notre rencontre. comparer: Les trois mois sont passés rapidement.

Comment: _...se sont écoulés_.

Answer (score 1):

« Trois mois ont passés » est incorrect, même si on  trouve [beaucoup de cas](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mois%20ont%20pass%C3%A9s%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) dans les livres .

[image]

Dans la langue écrite, en ordre de fréquences décroissantes, l'ordre est le suivant. ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mois+sont+pass%C3%A9s%2Cmois+ont+pass%C3%A9%2Cmois+se+sont+pass%C3%A9s&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmois%20sont%20pass%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmois%20ont%20pass%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmois%20se%20sont%20pass%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmois%20sont%20pass%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmois%20ont%20pass%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmois%20se%20sont%20pass%C3%A9s%3B%2Cc0))

- Trois mois ont passé
- Trois mois sont passés
- Trois mois se sont passés

[image]

Dans la langue parlée, l'ordre est préservé ; on ne dit pratiquement pas « se sont passés ».

Comment: Oui, j'ai oublié de supprimer le "s" dans _Trois mois ont passé_.

Comment: @Lambie 1/ Dans « Google Books » le mot « Google » modifie « Books» ; en français c'est l'inverse ; ex. : oiseau-mouche, timbre-poste, bateau-mouche, poisson-chat, … alors « livres Google ». 2/ …ne peut rien prouv**er** quant à la langue parlé**e**

Comment: Oui, je suis la reine de fôtes d'orthographe. Mais pour le fond, j'ai raison.

Comment: Google livres ne rien peut rien **prouver** quant à la langue **parlée**.

Comment: Ce n'est pas « Google livres » en français mais « Livres Googles », c'est à dire « les livres tels que Google les choisit et les utilise ».

Comment: https://books.google.fr/ Clique sur le titre: Google suivi du mot livres en dessous. Et ici aussi: https://books.google.fr/advanced_book_search. Why don't you deal with the difference between se passer and passer instead of worrying about my spelling?

Comment: 1/ Ils se trompent.  2/ Why not deal with … ? Because I am trying to do  as you do, I ignore what I am reading when it saves a moment or some trouble.